# Aplicativo android apresenta erro

Tags: json, android-studio

Boa noite

Eu estou aprendendo a usar o Android Studio. Estou tentando desenvolver um aplicativo que pega alguns dados json via url, mas ao roda a minha aplicação, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
02-01 23:30:35.700 14230-14230/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bd4730)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.net.exemplo.myapplication/br.net.exemplo.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at br.net.exemplo.myapplication.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:37)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at br.net.exemplo.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
02-01 23:30:36.990 14230-14230/br.net.exemplo.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

O que pode ser?

Obrigado

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity`: br.net.exemplo.myapplication. Você não declarou no Manifest.Xml a activity main.

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?